# How can I change my refresh rate without things looking pixelated?

Tags: drivers, display, display-resolution, amd-graphics

I have a new 75hz monitor.

I have an AMD Rx 570 graphics card running on Ubuntu 22.04. I have never changed or touched anything related to graphics driver, and just use what came with Ubuntu.

I wanted to change my refresh rate to 75hz. I went into display settings, and under refresh rate 74.97hz was a new option once I changed the monitor.

I selected 74.97 and everything went really pixelated, like the resolution was halved of something. It was unusable so I just reverted to 60hz.

Is there a problem with ubuntu not working on 75hz?

FYI I am am using X11 instead of Wayland because it works better with the games I play.